# How can I remove informative text in Vs 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I'm writing code in c# and the text that appears in the picture is constantly appearing. How can I remove it?

Comment: If the answer can help you to solve the problem, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information text called parameter information.
If you want to colse it you can choose Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>General and uncheck Parameter information.

[image]

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]